# Tengo un error con el *ngIf en Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

El ngIf no me lee los objetos dentro de un objeto en el html que podria ser?

en el data.component.html

```
    <h4>Formularios <small>data</small></h4>
<hr>
<form [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="guardarCambios()" novalidate="novalidate">

    <div formGroupName="nombrecompleto">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
            <div class="col-8">

                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre" formControlName="nombre">

                <!-- *ngIf="forma.get('nombrecompleto.nombre').errors?.required" -->

                <div class="form-group row form-control-feedback" *ngIf="forma.controls['nombrecompleto'].controls['nombre'].errors?.required">
                    El nombre es necesario.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="input-group col-md-8">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        Guardar
      </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    {{forma.valid}}

</form>
```

En el data.componen.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data',
  templateUrl: './data.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class DataComponent {

  forma:FormGroup;

  usuario:Object={
    nombrecompleto:{
      nombre:""
    }
  }

  constructor() {

    console.log(this.usuario);
    

    this.forma = new FormGroup({

      nombrecompleto: new FormGroup({

        nombre:new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)])

      })
    });
                
  }

  guardarCambios(){
    console.log(this.forma.value);
    console.log(this.forma);
    
  }

}
```

No me lo lee en el ngif de el html por que sera? hasta probe con .get que esta comentado ensima de nombre y tampoco funciono me dice que el 2° controls no lo encuentra "Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.ngtsc(2339)" ese es el error cuando le pongo el cursor enzima del 2° controls AYUDA por favor.

hay si me salen mas errores si lo coloco el el ngIf

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mira y ahora de ahi me sale un error en erors

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la propiedad controls hereda la interfaz [AbstractControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl) y esta misma no tiene la propiedad controls, aquí nace el error, lo mejor que podemos hacer es usar el método `get` que si esta contemplado en la interfaz y así nos deshacemos del problema

```
this.forma.controls["nombrecompleto"].get("nombre").errors?.required
```

EDIT:

El get también necesita un `?` delante porque puede devolver null, quedaría asi al final:

```
forma.controls['nombrecompleto'].get('nombre')?.errors?.required
```

luego hay otro problema, en el formControlName por que en el formulario `form` no existe el hijo `nombre`, el hijo `nombre` esta dentro de `nombrecompleto` y para acceder desde al html a `nombre` necesitamos decirle a angular quien es el padre del hijo (en este caso el padre es `nombrecompleto`), esto se lo podemos decir en el div superior al input con formGroupName

```
<div formGroupName="nombrecompleto" class="col-8">
```

luego de esto el formControlName del input si funcionaria

```
<input
  class="form-control"
  type="text"
  placeholder="Nombre"
  formControlName="nombre"
/>
```

el html final quedaría algo asi:

```
<h4>Formularios <small>data</small></h4>
<hr />
<form [formGroup]="forma" (ngSubmit)="guardarCambios()" novalidate="novalidate">
  <!-- formGroupName="nombrecompleto" -->
  <div>
    <!-- [ngClass]="{'has-danger': (forma.controls['nombre'].errors?.required || forma.controls['nombre'].errors?.minlength) && forma.touched}" -->
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Nombre</label>
      <div formGroupName="nombrecompleto" class="col-8">
        <input
          class="form-control"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Nombre"
          formControlName="nombre"
        />

        <!-- *ngIf="forma.get('nombrecompleto.nombre').errors?.required" -->
        <!-- *ngIf="forma.controls['nombrecompleto'].controls['nombre'].errors?.required" -->

        <div
          class="form-group row form-control-feedback"
          *ngIf="
            forma.controls['nombrecompleto'].get('nombre')?.errors?.required
          "
        >
          El nombre es necesario.
        </div>
        <div
          class="form-group row form-control-feedback"
          *ngIf="
            forma.controls['nombrecompleto'].get('nombre')?.errors?.minlength
          "
        >
          Por lo menos
          {{
            forma.controls["nombrecompleto"].get("nombre")?.errors?.minlength
              .requiredLength
          }}
          caracteres.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- [ngClass]="{'has-danger': (forma.controls['apellido'].errors?.required || forma.controls['apellido'].errors?.minlength) && forma.touched}" -->
    <div
      class="form-group row"
      [ngClass]="{
        'has-danger':
          (forma.controls['apellidor'].errors?.required ||
            forma.controls['apellidor'].errors?.minlength) &&
          forma.touched
      }"
    >
      <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Apellido</label>
      <div class="col-8">
        <input
          class="form-control"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Apellido"
          formControlName="apellidor"
        />
        <div
          class="form-group row form-control-feedback"
          *ngIf="forma.controls['apellidor'].errors?.required"
        >
          El apellido es necesario.
        </div>
        <div
          class="form-group row form-control-feedback"
          *ngIf="forma.controls['apellidor'].errors?.minlength"
        >
          Por lo menos
          {{ forma.controls["apellidor"].errors?.minlength.requiredLength }}
          caracteres.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div
    class="form-group row"
    [ngClass]="{
      'has-danger':
        (forma.controls['correo'].errors?.required ||
          forma.controls['correo'].errors?.pattern) &&
        forma.touched
    }"
  >
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Correo</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <input
        class="form-control"
        type="email"
        placeholder="Correo electrónico"
        formControlName="correo"
      />
      <div
        class="form-group row form-control-feedback"
        *ngIf="forma.controls['correo'].errors?.required"
      >
        El correo es necesario.
      </div>
      <div
        class="form-group row form-control-feedback"
        *ngIf="forma.controls['correo'].errors?.pattern"
      >
        Formato del correo no valido.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Pasatiempos</label>
    <div
      class="col-md-8"
      formArrayName="pasatiempos"
      *ngFor="
        let pasatiempo of forma.controls['pasatiempos'].value;
        let i = index
      "
    >
      <input type="text" class="form-control" [formControlName]="i" />
    </div>

    <button (click)="agregarPasatiempo()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
      Nuevo
    </button>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-2 col-form-label">&nbsp;</label>
    <div class="input-group col-md-8">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Guardar</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  {{ forma.valid }} {{ forma.valid }}
</form>
```

Comment: No me funciono osea lo que pasa es que al momento de usar el `*ngIf="forma.controls['nombrecompleto'].controls['nombre'].errors?.required` en el data.components.html me sale un error en el segudo controls y el error esta en la descripcion de la pregunta. Tambie use el `*ngIf="forma.get('nombrecompleto.nombre').errors?.required"` y falla

Comment: Con el código que te pase, que error te sale?

Comment: Por favor, si van a extender la pregunta con intentos adicionales, @Felipe, edita la pregunta e incluye lo que te salió cuando probaste el código en esta respuesta

Comment: @Franco donde debo colocar el codigo que me pasaste?

Comment: @Felipe En el ngIf

Comment: @Franco mira la pregunta realice lo que dijiste

Comment: @Felipe te faltaron las comillas del ngif, mira mi respuesta, la edite.

Comment: @Franco ya edite la respuesta pero me salen mas errores te puedo pasar el proyecto? por GitHub? para que lo analices? es un proyecto pequeño de aprendizaje puedo?

Comment: Si, pasalo por que no m estoy dando cuenta del error

Comment: [El link del repositorio del proyecto](https://github.com/AdrianFelipe04/formularios.git)   @Franco ahi esta perdone la demora

Comment: @Felipe solucionado

Comment: Que era bro @Franco

Answer (score 0):

`.controls` no contiene la propiedad get por que por defecto retorna un tipo `FormControls`. Es necesario que uses la aserción de tipos `as FormGroup` para que no te de el error.

En tu `component.ts`:

```js
obtenerFormGroup(campo: string): FormGroup {
  return this.forma.get(campo) as FormGroup
}
```

Y tu HTML quedaría asi:

```html
<div class="form-group row form-control-feedback" *ngIf="obtenerFormGroup('nombrecompleto').get('nombre').errors?.required">
  El nombre es necesario.
</div>
```

Te dejo un un ejemplo funcional [en stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uxffbp?file=src/app/app.component.html)